# Including Unchecked State in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am not a programmer, but I can understand things and can follow directions fairly well.

I implemented some JS I found on JSfiddle to save the state of checkboxes, and it works great. You check it, it stays checked on refresh.

The problem though, if you uncheck a box and refresh, it comes back checked. This is the Fiddle I used: 
[JS Fiddle for Saving Checked State with Cookies](https://jsfiddle.net/4ALFU/81/)

```
//===== Cookies Plugin=====   //

(function ($) {

        $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

            // key and at least value given, set cookie...
            if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value === null || value === undefined)) {
                options = $.extend({}, options);

                if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                    options.expires = -1;
                }

                if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                    var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                    t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
                }

                value = String(value);

                return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
            }

            // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
            options = value || {};
            var decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;

            var pairs = document.cookie.split('; ');
            for (var i = 0, pair; pair = pairs[i] && pairs[i].split('='); i++) {
                if (decode(pair[0]) === key) return decode(pair[1] || ''); // IE saves cookies with empty string as "c; ", e.g. without "=" as opposed to EOMB, thus pair[1] may be undefined
            }
            return null;
        };
    })(jQuery);

//======================================//

  $(document).ready(function () {

        var checkbox = $('#boxlawreg').find(':checkbox'), checkboxCookieName = 'checkbox-state';

        checkbox.each(function () {
            $(this).attr('checked', $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + $(this).attr('name')));
        });

        checkbox.click(function () {                
            $.cookie(checkboxCookieName + '|' + $(this).attr('name'), $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
```

Can anybody assist with how to make it work for checked and unchecked states?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody at work helped me by giving me this code, which works (note the classes for Input)

```
    // Avoid scoping issues by encapsulating code inside anonymous function
(function() {
  // variable to store our current state
  var cbstate;

  // bind to the onload event
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the current state from localstorage
    // State is stored as a JSON string
    cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');

    // Loop through state array and restore checked 
    // state for matching elements
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }

    // Get all checkboxes that you want to monitor state for
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');

    // Loop through results and ...
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {

      //bind click event handler
      cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // If checkboxe is checked then save to state
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }

    // Else remove from state
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }

    // Persist state
        localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
```